# ¿Como puedo solucionar este error?

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un programa para controlar los televisores remotamente, pero me sale este error.

```
Error: 
    Juans-MacBook-Pro:libLGTV_serial-master juanpablo$ python LGTV.py --togglepower
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LGTV.py", line 5, in <module>
    from libLGTV_serial import LGTV  File "/Users/juanpablo/Desktop/control tv/libLGTV_serial-master/libLGTV_serial.py", line 3, in <modul
e>
    import serialImportError: No module named serial
```

Código:

```
# Sample Windows script which uses the libLGTV_serial library
# Can be called, for example by doing "python LGTV.py --poweroff"
#
import sys
from libLGTV_serial import LGTV

model = '43LV640S'                    # Change this to your TV's model

# Change this to the serial port you're using
# On Linux it might look like '/dev/ttyS0'
# On a Mac it might look like '/dev/tty.usbmodemfa2321'
serial_port = "802MXTCQ2353"

# Verify passed command
if len(sys.argv) != 2: 
    print('Usage: {0} <command>'.format(sys.argv[0]))
    print('Example: {0} --togglepower'.format(sys.argv[0]))
    sys.exit(1)

tv = LGTV(model, serial_port)

# Example of adding a custom toggle command. Passing in '--toggleinput'
# will toggle between 'inputrgbpc' and 'inputdigitalcable'
tv.add_toggle('input', 'inputrgbpc', 'inputdigitalcable')

# Sometimes a single remote button press is detected as many. By debouncing a
# command, we make sure its only called once per button press.
tv.debounce('togglepower')

# Finally, send the command
# .send() Returns nothing on failure, 2-digit bytecode for status commands,
# and True for other commands
print(tv.send(sys.argv[1].lstrip("--")))
```

Comment: Hola JuanGonzález, por favor edita la pregunta para poner tanto código como error en modo texto. De ese modo serán más fáciles de leer y probar, y de ese modo será más fácil ayudarte. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más recomendaciones. Un saludo.

Comment: pip install pyserial o apt-get install python-serial

Comment: Ya instale el pyserial, pero me sale ese error.

Comment: ¿si haces `pip list | grep pyserial` te sale como instalado?

Comment: Si, me sale así pyserial   3.4

Comment: ¿Que versión de python usas? Si es la 3 debes instalarlo con `pip3`

Comment: Es esta Python 2.7.10

Comment: ¿Has instalado python con `brew`? Puede que haya un problema con los paths ¿Que salida te da `which -a python`? ¿Que salida te da `pip show pyserial`?

Comment: Este es el resultado si ejecuto pip show pyserial: /usr/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/pythonJuans-MacBook-Pro:libLGTV_serial-master juanpablo$ pip show pyserial
Name: pyserial
Version: 3.4
Summary: Python Serial Port Extension
Home-page: https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial
Author: Chris Liechti
Author-email: cliechti@gmx.net
License: BSD
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:

Comment: Me sale es ningún modulo llamado serial:  No module named serial

Comment: ¿Que salida te da `echo $PATH`? ¿Estan  `/usr/bin/python` y `/usr/local/bin/python`? prueba a añadir la ruta del módulo al `$PYTHONPATH` de la siguiente manera `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Comment: ¿Como lo puedo poner?¿puedes editar el código que tengo arriba?

Comment: tienes que poner `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` en la terminal

Comment: Mira, ya sale esto: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LGTV.py", line 21, in <module>    tv = LGTV(model, serial_port)
  File "/Users/juanpablo/Desktop/control tv/libLGTV_serial-master/libLGTV_serial.py", line 137, in __in
it__
    self.codes = all_codes[self.model[2:]]
KeyError: 'LV640S'
Juans-MacBook-Pro:libLGTV_serial-master juanpablo$, Y el key es: 43LV640S

Comment: edita tu pregunta y pon el error como bloque de código para que se pueda leer bien, de todas maneras según [la wiki de la libreria](https://github.com/suan/libLGTV_serial/wiki/Supported-TV-Models) ese modelo no está soportado